# Do I need to use AutoLayout for different iOS sizes or could I design separately for each phone?

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

Am I forced to use AutoLayout to make my design compatible to different iOS sizes or, could I design separately for each phone size and submit my final Xcode project separately for each iPhone screen size to app store?

Comment: You can't really submit different apps for different screen sizes as it would cause confusion for users as there is no way to limit downloads to a specific device - the user would need to select the right app and I suspect it is likely that Apple would reject your apps for not working correctly on all devices.  In short, use Autolayout.  If done properly then this will also give you a good chance of supporting any new devices Apple may release.

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8QA9IYB67o

Answer (score 0):

You should not release different apps for specific device types. Your users still could install the iPhone5 version on an iPhone6+ since the AppStore has no means of restricting app download based on such characteristics (apart from iPhone vs. iPad, of course).

One way to go without using AutoLayout is this: you can create different UI layouts (with Interface Builder or programmatically) for different device types. For example, you could create separate storyboards for all iPhone/iPad sizes you want to support. On startup (in your app delegate's `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`), you would manually load the storyboard for the current device size (with `storyboardWithName:bundle:`) and use `instantiateInitialViewController` to get the initial view controller, which you would set as `rootViewController`of your window.

That said, I would strongly advise against using this approach. For one, you'd have to manually replicate every UI change for all storyboards; furthermore, you will lack support for future device sizes. Really, better go for AutoLayout :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not forced, but Auto Layout will give you adaptive layout, and Size Classes will alter that layout for a specific screen size and orientation (if needed).

That's the way it should be done. **Auto Layout** + **Size Classes**.

Answer (score 0):

xibs/storyoards can't have multiple layouts in 'one unit'. size classes require auto layout. (Size classes only modify the way you see your auto layout)

---

if you don't wanna use size classes, load differently named xibs/storyboards for each device. (which will be a hassle to maintain!)